# Python3 Module has no asset erros

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, attributeerror, area

I have never come across this before when working with Python.  When I type:

> > > import areas  - no errors - import works

when I type:

> > > areas.triangle(3,5) : I get this error:

AttributeError: module 'areas' has no attribute 'triangle'

What I can see from looking inside the package folder is that there are no functions for anything the areas module is supposed to do.

When I type

> > > dir(areas) I get

['Test', 'Tester', '**builtins**', '**cached**', '**doc**', '**file**', '**loader**', '**name**', '**package**', '**path**', '**spec**', 'config', 'exception', 'parameters', 'subroutines', 'test', 'tester', 'util']

I checked

> > > print(areas.**file**) I get

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/areas/**init**.py

I can't figure out what is happening.  Anyone have any similar issues or what I am doing to cause the issue (Wrong version of areas, wrong directory)

Thanks for the help.  Again, no errors when I import the areas module in python3

I attempted to do this same import using python- (not python3)

I assume that if the package imports without errors, it thinks its okay?

---------- Follow Up.

I was following my python instructor online.   He imported the 'areas' package and then did a cat on areas.py and got the following response.
cat areas.py

import math

def triangle(base, height):

return base*height/2

def rectangle(base, height):

return base*height

def circle(radius):

return math.pi*(radius**2)

Comment: Maybe you meant to install the `area` package, not the `areas` package?

Comment: In any case, it seems you installed a different module than the one you intended.  The only module I can find that is named `areas` has nothing to do with triangles.

Comment: Do you remember when/how you installed the `areas` package?  Were you following some instructions?

Answer (score 0):

UGH... Really sorry for the confusion.   But I appreciate all the responses, and I did learn from them.

The instructor had actually "CREATED' the file called areas.py and added the code to it that I showed.   I created the file areas.py and then EVERYTHING wored great.

Again, I appreciate the help.  (Sorry I am new to Python)